# Reading XML file in php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file, but it's not reading when i try to get certain values from it. Below is the xml

```
<PaymentNotificationRequest>
<RouteId>HTTPSERVICE</RouteId>
<ServiceUrl>http://62.173.32.122:8085/</ServiceUrl>
<ServiceUsername/>
<ServicePassword/>
<FtpUrl>http://62.173.32.122:8085/</FtpUrl>
<FtpUsername/>
<FtpPassword/>
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <ProductGroupCode>HTTPSERVICE</ProductGroupCode>
        <PaymentLogId>12589</PaymentLogId>
        <CustReference>806656919</CustReference>
        <AlternateCustReference>abc@yahoo.com:</AlternateCustReference>
        <Amount>500.00</Amount>
        <PaymentStatus>0</PaymentStatus>
        <PaymentMethod>Debit Card</PaymentMethod>
        <PaymentReference>FBN|Web|3IWP0076|TST|120314160934|00000031</PaymentReference>
        <TerminalId/>
        <ChannelName>WEB</ChannelName>
        <Location/>
        <IsReversal>False</IsReversal>
        <PaymentDate>03/12/2014 16:09:34</PaymentDate>
        <SettlementDate>03/13/2014 00:00:01</SettlementDate>
        <InstitutionId>TST</InstitutionId>
        <InstitutionName>Test Scheme</InstitutionName>
        <BranchName/>
        <BankName>First Bank of Nigeria Plc</BankName>
        <FeeName/>
        <CustomerName>Nathan Henry</CustomerName>
        <OtherCustomerInfo>|</OtherCustomerInfo>
        <ReceiptNo>1407107249</ReceiptNo>
        <CollectionsAccount>9393939393</CollectionsAccount>
        <ThirdPartyCode/>
        <PaymentItems>
            <PaymentItem>
                <ItemName>Fund Wallet</ItemName>
                <ItemCode>1010</ItemCode>
                <ItemAmount>500.00</ItemAmount>
                <LeadBankCode>FBN</LeadBankCode>
                <LeadBankCbnCode>011</LeadBankCbnCode>
                <LeadBankName>First Bank of Nigeria Plc</LeadBankName>
            </PaymentItem>
        </PaymentItems>
        <BankCode>FBN</BankCode>
        <CustomerAddress/>
        <CustomerPhoneNumber/>
        <DepositorName/>
        <DepositSlipNumber>FBN|WEB|QTELL|12-03-</DepositSlipNumber>
        <PaymentCurrency>566</PaymentCurrency>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
```

I want to be able to read values in , , , and even .

But this is what i have

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
foreach($xml as $value){
    echo $value->Payment->Amount;
    ......
}
```

These do not return any value. Can someone please, help?

Comment: Please read through your question yourself. Your formatting is not working, you have an issue with the display of the xml elements in the middle of your question.

Comment: I hope the values in the xml are not real ones... because some people could find them interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot the "Payments" tag :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
foreach($xml->Payments->Payment as $value){
    echo $value->Amount;
    ......
}
```

You can find other examples at [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

- [Example with foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#96764)